# Address user after login to a specific page based on the type of role he has

Tags: php

As the title suggests, I would like the user to login to two specific pages based on the type of role.

By default in the role field the letter "N" is defined

So if it is equal to N, go to
Otherwise go to

login.php:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>

<?php

$messaggio = "";

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

include 'FILE_DI_CONNESSIONE.php';

//REAL_ESCAPE_STRING ANTI STRINGA BUCA DB

$email = $VARIABILE_FILE_DI_CONNESSIONE->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);

$password = $VARIABILE_FILE_DI_CONNESSIONE->real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

$query = $VARIABILE_FILE_DI_CONNESSIONE->query("SELECT id, password FROM tabella WHERE email='$email'");

if ($query->num_rows > 0) {

$data = $query->fetch_array();

if (password_verify($password, $data['password'])) {

$_SESSION['NOME_SESSIONE'] = true;

//IMPLEMENTAZIONE SICUREZZA PER ACCESSO AI DATI SOLO SE LA SESSIONE DELLA LOGIN PAGE E' UGUALE ALLA PAGINA DOPO DEL LOGIN

?>

<?php
}else

$messaggio = "Gentilmente inserisci correttamente la tua username e la tua password.";

}}

?>
<?php if ($messaggio != "") echo $messaggio . "<br><br>"; ?>


<form method="post" action="index.php">

<input class="form-control" name="email" type="email" placeholder="email..."><br>

<input class="form-control" minlength="5" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password..."><br>

<input class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" type="submit" value="Log In"><br>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to implement a redirect. But assuming the variable with the role is $role and that can be either N or O you can redirect this way

```
if($role == 'N')
{
   // Role N
   ?><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=page1.php"/><?php 
}
elseif($role == 'O')
{
   // Role O
   ?><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=page2.php"/><?php 
}
else
{
   // no role?
}
```

Besides a meta refresh, you can also redirect like this:

```
if($role == 'N')
{
   // Role N
   header("Location: page1.php"); 
}
elseif($role == 'O')
{
   // Role O
   header("Location: page2.php"); 
}
else
{
   // no role?
}
```

Edit: Try this for the entire code:

```
<?php session_start();

$messaggio = "";

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

include 'FILE_DI_CONNESSIONE.php';

//REAL_ESCAPE_STRING ANTI STRINGA BUCA DB

$email = $VARIABILE_FILE_DI_CONNESSIONE->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);

$password = $VARIABILE_FILE_DI_CONNESSIONE->real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

$query = $VARIABILE_FILE_DI_CONNESSIONE->query("SELECT id, password, role FROM tabella WHERE email='$email'");

if ($query->num_rows > 0) {

$data = $query->fetch_array();

if (password_verify($password, $data['password'])) {

$_SESSION['NOME_SESSIONE'] = true;

//IMPLEMENTAZIONE SICUREZZA PER ACCESSO AI DATI SOLO SE LA SESSIONE DELLA LOGIN PAGE E' UGUALE ALLA PAGINA DOPO DEL LOGIN
    if($data['role'] == 'N')
    {
       // Role N
       ?><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=page1.php"/><?php 
    }
    elseif($data['role'] == 'O')
    {
       // Role O
       ?><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=page2.php"/><?php 
    }
    else
    {
       // no role?
    }


}else

$messaggio = "Gentilmente inserisci correttamente la tua username e la tua password.";

}}

?>
<?php if ($messaggio != "") echo $messaggio . "<br><br>"; ?>


<form method="post" action="index.php">

<input class="form-control" name="email" type="email" placeholder="email..."><br>

<input class="form-control" minlength="5" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password..."><br>

<input class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" type="submit" value="Log In"><br>

</form>
```

Comment: i don 't know why but not work, maybe i wrong to implement the if cycle into my code, can u write te right code?